# Does pyserial send msb first or lsb first

Tags: python

I have a small question. I am planning on using pyserial to communicate with a serial device. So lets say I do a `serial.write("ABCD")` , will pyserial send the 8 bits of `D` first or 8 bits of `A` first? IS there somewhere that I can configure pyserial to do what I like or should I byteswap the orginal data itself?  Also within D itself what is sent out first. Just for sake of simpliyfing things lets say D stands for 01001001. Will 1 be sent first or 0 be sent first?

Comment: It is going to write in the order given.  You'll need to reorder the characters yourself if you want them sent in a different order.

Comment: I understand I can reorder the characters. But I need to know the order first. Can you let me know what it will send first when I write serial.write("ABCD") ? A or D ? And within D itself (assuming it 01001001) 1 or 0 first ?

Comment: It will write A first.

Comment: The order that the bits are sent is based on the hardware, but if you are sending data on an RS-232 serial port, look at the RS-232 specification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232